# GAE + Spring + JDO - PersistenceManagerFactory initialization error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, log4j, jdo

I have a standard PMF class:

```
public class PMF {

    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory persistenceManagerFactory = JDOHelper
        .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {
    }

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return persistenceManagerFactory;
    }

}
```

Running on a local appengine server,
when I first call PMF.get(), I get the following exception:

```
javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1193)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1093)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at com.myapp.framework.PMF.<clinit>(PMF.java:17)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    ...
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.datanucleus.util.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:135)
    at org.datanucleus.util.NucleusLogger.getLoggerInstance(NucleusLogger.java:140)
    at org.datanucleus.util.NucleusLogger.<clinit>(NucleusLogger.java:106)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginRegistryFactory.newInstance(PluginRegistryFactory.java:104)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginRegistryFactory.newPluginRegistry(PluginRegistryFactory.java:63)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(PluginManager.java:61)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createPluginManager(PluginManager.java:427)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:224)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:204)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:182)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:409)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:294)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    ... 82 more
```

My logging setup is quite standard:
- a logging.properties in the WEB-INF folder and referenced in the appengine-web.xml
- a log4j.properties at the root of my src folder:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console

# Configure the console as our one appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

# tighten logging on the DataNucleus Categories
log4j.category.DataNucleus.JDO=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Persistence=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Cache=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.MetaData=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.General=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Utility=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Transaction=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Datastore=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.ClassLoading=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Plugin=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.ValueGeneration=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Enhancer=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.SchemaTool=WARN, A1
```

The libs included in my lib folder are:
- All the GAE lib from the sdk included using the eclipse google plugin
- Spring MVC, Jackson and Aspectj included using ivy and the ivy eclipse plugin:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="3.2.0.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.jackson" name="jackson-mapper-asl" rev="1.9.11" />
    <dependency org="org.aspectj" name="aspectjrt" rev="1.7.1" />
    <dependency org="org.aspectj" name="aspectjweaver" rev="1.7.1" />
</dependencies>
```

I really don't understand why it fail as normally log4j is supported by GAE.

Comment: It seems you did not add Log4j jar to the project or this jar is not uploaded to GAE server.

Comment: In fact, I have a log4j-1.2.14.jar from spring dependencies in my lib folder and it is well copied to GAE server but it seems GAE prevent class loading.
When I exclude log4j from spring dependencies, I no longer get the error. With this solution, may I loose some logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I excluded log4j from spring dependencies and I no longer get the error.
In my ivy file:

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="3.2.0.RELEASE">
    <exclude org="log4j" module="log4j" />
</dependency>
```